# Accessing json output by zendframework with jquery

Tags: php, javascript, jquery, json

```
{
   "code":100,
   "data":{
      "month":[
         {
            "yearText":"2011",
            "months":[
               {
                  "monthText":"6",
                  "days":[
                     {
                        "dayText":"13",
                        "cios":[
                           {
                              "status":"continues",
                              "start":"23:00:00",
                              "end":"23:59:59",
                              "id":12
                           }
                        ],
                        "bois":[
                           {
                              "status":"continues",
                              "start":"23:30:00",
                              "end":"23:59:59",
                              "id":12
                           }
                        ]
                     },
                     {
                        "dayText":"14",
                        "cios":[
                           {
                              "status":"continued",
                              "start":"00:00:00",
                              "end":"01:00:00",
                              "id":12
                           },
                           {
                              "status":"within",
                              "start":"11:42:14",
                              "end":"11:43:45",
                              "id":11
                           }
                        ],
                        "bois":[
                           {
                              "status":"continued",
                              "start":"00:00:00",
                              "end":"00:30:00",
                              "id":12
                           },
                           {
                              "status":"within",
                              "start":"11:42:39",
                              "end":"11:43:33",
                              "id":11
                           }
                        ]
                     }
                  ]
               }
            ]
         }
      ],
      "next":"\/attendance\/get-history\/2011\/07",
      "previous":"\/attendance\/get-history\/2011\/05"
   },
   "msg":"Attendance history of John Doe on June, 2011."
}
```

this json output file was generated by zendframework, i am trying to access the objects inside the "months" : string through jquery, which looks like an array.

i have tried to access them like usual objects as in month.yearText with no luck, i am not doing it right of coz.

any help? please.

thanks

Comment: You can format you code by selecting it and a click on the `{}` button.

Comment: You said it already: *month looks like an array*. How do you access an array?

Comment: @Felix Kling: Well, Javascript is pretty flexible. So you could either use month['yearText'] or month.yearText to access the value when you have an associative array (see [Javascript - Objects as associative array](http://www.quirksmode.org/js/associative.html)). @hilarl: Could you post the JS code you are using or - failing that - have you tried using Firebug to check if your assumption is correct?

Comment: @wimvds: Actually this was a rhetorical question ;) And I meant arrays and not objects...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try jQuery's `parseJSON()` function

Something like this:

```
var obj = jQuery.parseJSON('{"name":"John"}'); 
alert( obj.name === "John" );
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to use `month[0].yearText`, because month is array.